# How to write random function using Beanshell postprocessor using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I Have 3 set of correlation variables dependent on each other.

If I send 1st occurrence for 1 value then I need to send same to remaining values as well. Every time I need to pick random value.

So I need to write random function for one of the value `id_matchnr` and need to same it variable (var) and passing it to other variables `(id_details_var , id_details2_Var)`

I tried using below functions but none of them worked

```
int count = ${__Random(1,counter,)};

int count = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, counter);

math.random(1,counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Beanshell, it's some form of a performance anti-pattern. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
2. It looks like you don't need any scripting at all, you can generate a random number and save it into a JMeter Variable using [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random)

   [image]

Comment: how can i generate random number using regex variable matchnr and where i need to declare it?